# how to make <li> clickable and get its data-action value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm using a jQuery bootgrid but I modify its navigation.

The original bootgrid:

[image]

My modified bootgrid:
[image]

As you can see, I hide the search textbox and pagination dropdown on the original bootgrid, and instead use my own navigation design.

On my navigation, plus sign for making new user,trash for bulk delete, search sign, reload sign and pagination.

[image]

My problem is the pagination, it is not clickable and doesn't close once I click the li that I want (ex. 25 per page). Also how can I get the data-action value? I try to put a js function onclick="getPage(10)" on one of the li and it is working, which means that li recognize the click, but instead of doing that, I want a solution where I use jquery to get that data-action value.

This is my html

```html
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-more-vert"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"> 
        <li>
            <a data-action="10" page="10" onclick="getPage(10)">10 per page</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-action="25" page="25">25 per page</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-action="50" page="50">50 per page</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-action="100" page="100">100 per page</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-action="-1" page="100">All</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This is my code on my bootgrid.

```
  var table = $('#settings-user-list');

table.bootgrid({
    css     : {
        icon        : 'zmdi icon',
        iconColumns : 'zmdi-view-list',
        iconDown    : 'zmdi-caret-down',
        iconRefresh : 'zmdi-refresh',
        iconUp      : 'zmdi-caret-up',
    },
    labels  : {
        noResults   : noResult,
        loading     : loadingTable,
    },
    ajax         : true,
    url          : '/action/list',
    selection    : true,
    rowCount     : [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
    multiSelect  : true,
    navigation   : 2
});
```

Comment: what happens when you attach jQuery click handler to these anchor tags?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Add this code and check your console:
`$(".dropdown-menu li a").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log( $(this).data("action") );
});//click handler()`

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj it gets the value!

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj,  $(".dropdown").removeClass("open"); I add this code inside that function so the dropdown will close. You should put your comment as an answer and I'll vote it as best. Thanks!

Comment: So you get the `data-action` value. Now you can use it further according to your requirements. Also you should keep your page attribute also as a data attribute i.e. `data-page="50"` etc.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj, Why should I keep the page attribute? I remove it and it still works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143357/discussion-between-mohit-bhardwaj-and-oblivion-coder).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have write following line to make your table to jquery bootgrid.

```
$(function () {
   $("#tableId").bootgrid();
});
```